# eclipse - cannot get project export/dependencies working

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-kepler

Ok. I am using eclipse kepler.

Ihave an eclipse project called 'afd-core'. It has some classes, and a directory etc/hibernate containing hibernate config - lookup.hbm.xml.

I have another project afd-public. It is a webapp, and needs the stuff in afd-core on it's classpath.

And I think I have tried everything.

afd-public->project referencers: added add-core as a referenced project
afd-public->java build path->projects: added afd-core
afd-public->java build path->order and export: marked afd-core as exported
afd-core->java build path->added etc/hibernate as a classpath entry
afd-core->order and export->marked etc/hibernate as exported

Didn't work. When I run add-public as a web app, complains that it cant find the hibernate config.

So I made etc/hibernate a source rather than a class direcrory. Still didn't work.

Explicitly added add-core/etc/hibernate as a class directory in the add-public project. Still didnt work. Marked those class drectories as 'exported'. Still didn't work.

Manually copied the hibernate config into afd-public/webapp/WEB-INF/classes . Ok, it finds the hibernate config, but it does not find the core class files.

In other words, the afd-public webapp is not including dependencies from afd-core AT ALL, not in any way, shape, or form into the webapp that it deploys locally to tomcat. Whether or not I mark them as exported from afd-core. Whether or not I include the project or the directories explicitly. Whether or not I do or dont export them from the afd-public webapp.

Nothing. nada. Won't go.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Goddamnit - I needed to fiddle with Deployment Assembly in afd-public. It seems that  there are a couple of ways to do it.

I can include afd-public/build/classes and afd-public/etc/hibernate and have them deployed to WEBINF/classes, or I can deploy the add-core jarfile to lib.

To get the afd-core jarfile correct, I create afd-core as a j2ee "utility project" and check that the Deployment Assembly there is correct. Which it is.